# wkhtmltopdf in Rails with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to generate a PDF file based on an HTML file in a Rails app. I search and I found this wkhtmltopdf engine, but when I try to generate a pdf appending the '.pdf' sufix in my pages it seems to be in a loop that never ends unless I stop the server, which show this error:

```
command failed: "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--quiet" "-" "-"
```

I'm using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf-binary gems and MacOS Lion. Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you follow the exact instructions [HERE](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) then your issues should go away.  I've used this on several projects without issue.  You should also know that there is an issue with scaling content should you happen to deploy to ubuntu and that you need to update wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I've already followed these instructions, but I gave it a try again and guess what...it worked! I'm trying to understand what I made different. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, this line was missing (in `config/initializers/pdfkit.rb`):
`config.root_url = "http://localhost"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. had this too.  There is a bug in the gem version of wkhtmltopdf.  Download the current release and the convert call will eventually come back.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf.dmg&can=2&q=